# hey guys, i need some help to add some features to civicrm locally using phpstorm?

Tags: drupal, developer, civicrm-buildkit

the question is how to edit something in contact page and how to debug my code.
is there anyway to debug it without install it again to DRUPAL and test my code if its work or not.

Answer (score 1):

start here to start learning about how use to phpstorm and xdebug:
https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/tools/phpstorm/